# Execute formula on contents of a cell and provide output in the same cell

Tags: excel, vba, date, format

I want to write a macro that will format a range of period dates (Month & Year).  The report puts out each period as number in mmyy format (examples: 922 is September 2022, 1222 is December 2022, 123 is January 2023, etc.)

What I want to accomplish is to select the range of dates and have them converted to a date in mmm-yy (Dec-22, Jan-23, Feb-23) format so that they can sorted oldest to newest.

I'm not sure how to convert the number 123 into a date and format it display Jan-23 without using a formula and a helper row, which I do not want to do.

Any advice?

[image: Example]

Comment: What rule determines the year in each case (2022 vs 2023) ?

Comment: the last two digits of the number in the Period field would be the year 20XX.

Comment: My reading comprehension fails again...

Answer (score 0):

The VBA equivalent to the worksheet function DATE is DateSerial. They take the same arguments.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ConvertStrToDate()
    Dim rngPeriods As Range, rngPeriod As Range, strDate As String, datDate As Date

    Set rngPeriods = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A7")

    For Each rngPeriod In rngPeriods
        strDate = Format(rngPeriod.Value, "0000")
        datDate = DateSerial(Right(strDate, 2), Left(strDate, 2), 1)
        rngPeriod.Value = datDate
    Next rngPeriod

    rngPeriods.NumberFormat = "mmm-yy"

    Set rngPeriods = Nothing
End Sub
```

Note that I converted your integer into a four-character string to make the parsing easier.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  I had to change the Set Rng to "Selection" since my list will always be a different length, but it is doing exactly what I need it to do!